# android. Как создать отдельный ресурс для разрешения 540px x 960px

Tags: ресурсы, android

Доброго времени суток. Пишу Виджет для андроид и столкнулся с проблемой. Виджет смотрится более-менее одинаково на всех устройствах, кроме разрешения 540px x 960px. Именно для этого разрешения нужно создать отдельный ресурс values, в котором будет хранится отличный файл dimension.
Если создаю values-w360dp, то все устройства с большим разрешением, чем 540px x 960px начинают ссылаться именно на него. Чего не должно происходить
Как сделать отдельный ресурс именно для разрешения 540px x 960px?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
res/layout-w540dp-h960dp/my_layout.xml
```

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)

Comment: Нет, так не получается. Даже если я напишу values-w360dp-h640dp. Где 360dp=540px, а 640 dp=960px. То этот ресурс не подгружается. Если оставляю values-w360dp, то все устройства с шириной больше 360dp начинают его использовать. Мне же нужно, чтобы этот ресурс подгружался только для разрешения 540px x 960px

Comment: вообще имеет смысл глянуть на ваш layout и смотреть, что вас там конкретно не устраивает. Пользоваться wrap_content, match_parent.